# add a column to a table with 4 possible default value based on logical argument

Tags: mysql, alter-table

How can I add a column to a table with the number 1 to 4 based on each row meeting certain criteria?

Suppose I have a table:
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoFEj.png) 
with two columns (ID) and (RESULTS) and that I want to add a third column called (SCORE).

I want to give a score (between 1 and 4) to each row in my column based on whether the numbers in column (RESULTS) meet certain criteria.

If the RESULT is negative, I want to give it a score of 1,
If the RESULT is less than 30, a score of 2,
less than 100 a score of 3
and greater than 100 a score of 4

I have tried using the CASE statement but cannot seem to get it to work;
I searched on the topics about constraints but they always seem to have two arguments - I need 4

Comment: Your question isnt clear. Show better examples and db schema and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the answer, as more details were given in the question (and to fix some errors)

Please remember to change table_name and trigger_name to appropriate names :).

SOLUTION:

You should first of all add the third column to the table

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN SCORE INT;
```

You should add the trigger to set the SCORE for the new rows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SET NEW.SCORE = CASE WHEN NEW.RESULTS < 0 THEN 1 WHEN NEW.RESULTS < 30 THEN 2 WHEN NEW.RESULTS < 100 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And you should initialize SCORE values for rows existing in the table

```
UPDATE      table_name t
    SET     t.SCORE = CASE WHEN t.RESULTS < 0 THEN 1 WHEN t.RESULTS < 30 THEN 2 WHEN t.RESULTS < 100 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Can I check: Do I still write the ALTER statement after this? I am slightly unclear as to how the insert of the new column occurs and how I get to name it (unless I follow with ALTER....AS something

Comment: I dont know if you get notified when i edit the answer, but I have updated it with required alters and updates needed for the whole solution. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks once again for sharing your knowledge, that helped a lot.